# using NextAuth with my NextJS app I have error when I switch my app from the standard localhost root to a basePath

Tags: next.js, next-auth, base-path

my next.config.js file

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const basePath = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH;

const nextConfig = {


reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true,
    basePath: `${basePath}`,
    assetPrefix: `${basePath}/`,

    experimental: {
      appDir: true,
    },
    
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

my .env.local file

```js
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/myapp/api/auth
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://localhost:8000/backend/
NEXT_PUBLIC_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIMIT=120
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH=/myapp
NEXT_PUBLIC_SESSION_BASE_PATH=/myapp/api/auth
NEXTAUTH_DEBUG=true
NEXTAUTH_BASE_PATH=/myapp
```

my LoginForm

```js
"use client"
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

const LoginForm = () => {
    const basePath = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH;

    const baseUrlCallback = async (baseUrl: string) => {
        const modifiedUrl = `${baseUrl}${basePath}`;
        console.log("modify URL", modifiedUrl)
        return modifiedUrl;
      };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Login FORM has basePath",basePath)
        const username = e.target.username.value;
        const password = e.target.password.value;
        username.length > 0 && await signIn("credentials", {
            //basePath: `${basePath}/api/auth`,
            baseUrl: baseUrlCallback,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            redirect: true,
            callbackUrl: "/myapp/dashboard",
          }); 
 
    };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} action="myapp/api/auth/callback/credentials">
        <label className="form-group has-float-label mb-4">
            <input className="form-control" id="username" type="text"/>
            <span>Username</span>
        </label>
        <label className="form-group has-float-label mb-4">
            <input className="form-control" type="password" id="password" />
            <span>Password</span>
        </label>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
            <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-shadow" type="submit">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default LoginForm
```

when I submit the form, it calls http://localhost:3000/api/auth/providers and returns 404 as it ignores the basePath and I get forwarded to error message to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error. Any ideas how to make it work?

I have also tried to make sure the URL that is submitted to NextAuth is the correct one, but it seems that this code does not come to be executed:

```js
const handler: NextApiHandler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    const basePath = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH;
    const originalUrl = req.url;
    req.url = `${basePath}${originalUrl}`;

    console.log("INTERCEPT NEXT AUTH:", req.url, originalUrl)
    
    return NextAuth(req, res, authOptions); 
};

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `signIn` method uses the environment variable `NEXTAUTH_URL` to redirect after action unless you [specify a callbackurl](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#specifying-a-callbackurl) on top of it  so you have to update `NEXTAUTH_URL` as well

Comment: I have removed the redirect that I was using in the signIn function but the behavior remains the same. Immediately as I submit the form, I am forwarded to the error page by Nextauth as the call to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/providers returns 404. In my .env.local I have configured NEXTAUTH_URL as follows: NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/myapp/api/auth but for some reason Nextauth defaults to no basePath

Comment: try to reload your app

Comment: I get same behavior, having "next": "^13.4.8", "next-auth": "^4.22.1". I think somehow the url in the signIn function defaults to the initial values in the parse-url.ts from the next-auth/utils where InternalUrl is declared